# How can i get only the name of an image in a variable in flask?

Tags: python, flask

```
def upload_image():  # put application's code here
    if request.method == "POST":
        image = request.files.get('file', '')
        print(image)
```

I want to get the name as 'new.jpg' in a variable but instead i am getting

> <FileStorage: 'new.jpg' ('image/jpeg')>
> as output

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filename` attr:

```
def upload_image():
    if request.method == "POST":
        image = request.files.get('file', '')
        image_name = image.filename
        print(image_name)
```